# How to deny SSH Connection from other user

Tags: sshd

I need to know is there is any other way to deny ssh entry other than `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If any please let me know.

Comment: What does deny ssh entry exactly means? If you want someone to access sftp and not access ssh then you can simply set the default shell to /usr/sbin/nologin in /etc/passwd and they won't be able to log in via ssh, but they will be able to sftp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the file at `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

**Testing**

- I added a new user as **testuser** using the `adduser` command.
- I added the below entry in my `/etc/ssh/sshd.deny` file. (If it
  doesn't exist you can create the file).

  ```
  testuser
  ```
- Now, I added the below entry in my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file. It is a
  good practice to backup your existing `sshd` file before making any
  changes.

  ```
  auth required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ssh/sshd.deny
  onerr=succeed
  ```
- Restart your `ssh` service.
- Now, I tried `ssh testuser@myhostname` and I get the **permission
  denied** error.
- From my log file `/var/log/auth.log` when I tested, I see the below
  information.

  ```
  Oct  7 10:24:49 ramesh-pc sshd[4522]: pam_listfile(sshd:auth): Refused user testuser for service sshd
  ```

**References**

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-pam-configuration-that-allows-or-deny-login-via-the-sshd-server.html

Comment: I'm sincerely curious: what's the point of leaving an almost empty answer and edit it later? Be the first?

Comment: @spider, well, that was not correct and I accept it was wrong of me to post an answer without actually testing. I had discussed in the chat regarding this and I was told it is not the right way to do things. I am sorry for that :)

Comment: No problem, Ramesh, I was not pointing fingers. Also, I stepped into your answers before and, when complete ;-), they are really well written, tested and useful. +1'ing this as well.